# Calculating multiplicative inverse in a finite field

Tags: math, haskell, cryptography, abstract-algebra

I've written an [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xgcd) function

```
xgcd :: FFElem -> FFElem -> (FFElem, FFElem)
```

that, for *nonzero* finite field elements *a,b* ∈ [GF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_field)(*p<sup>m</sup>*), calculates *s* and *t* such that *sa* + *tb* = 1. **Is there a way I can use `xgcd` to calculate multiplicative inverses in the field?** That is, given *a* ∈ GF(*p<sup>m</sup>*), I want to calculate *b* such that *ab* = 1 ∈ GF(*p<sup>m</sup>*).

---

I've also implemented the functions

```
(+)       :: FFElem -> FFElem -> FFElem
(-)       :: FFElem -> FFElem -> FFElem
(*)       :: FFElem -> FFElem -> FFElem
(^)       :: FFElem -> Integer -> FFElem
ffQuotRem :: FFElem -> FFElem -> (FFElem, FFElem)
degree    :: FFElem -> Integer
```

Where `(+)`, `(-)`, `(*)`, `(^)`, and `ffQuotRem` behave as you would expect and `degree` is the usual [Euclidean function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Definition) for finite fields (the degree of the polynomial representation of the field element).

(Answers don't necessarily need to be in Haskell.)

Comment: What does your `xgcd` function compute? How do you define the greatest common divisor in a field, where every non-zero element divides every non-zero element?

Comment: @Joni: I see what you mean now. That wasn't the normal definition of gcd. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: What does `xgcd` compute really? Given non-zero `a`, for every `t` in the field you can find `s = (1-tb)/a` that satisfies the equation, so `xgcd` is not well defined by that equation alone...

Comment: @Joni: I really screwed up this question... Let F = Z/pZ, f(x) irreducible in F[x], and GF(p^m) = F[x]/(f(x)). My mistake was that `xgcd a b` actually runs in F[x], not F[x]/(f(x)). That is, it calculates s and t **in F[x]** such that sa' + tb' = gcd(a',b'), where a',b' are the least degree elements in the congruence classes *a,b*, respectively. I'll think it through more carefully and try to salvage the question in the next couple days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some steps toward an answer. First, consider the ring `Z/nZ` which is a field if `n` is prime. We can give a simple routine to compute the multiplicative inverse of an element `a`

```
-- | Compute the inverse of a in the field Z/nZ.
inverse' a n = let (s, t) = xgcd n a
                   r      = s * n + t * a
                in if r > 1
                    then Nothing
                    else Just (if t < 0 then t + n else t)
```

Its type is `inverse :: Integral a => a -> a -> Maybe a` because it allows for non-prime `n`, when the multiplicative inverse does not exist.

If a field is not a prime field, then it is a field extension of a prime field `K = Z/nZ` for some prime `n`, and is isomorphic to `K[x]/p` for some polynomial `p`. In particular, we require that there is a function

```
degree :: Polynomial -> Integer
```

that tells us the degree of a polynomial, and a partial function

```
project :: Integral a => Polynomial -> Maybe a
```

that projects a polynomial of degree 0 down to its underlying field in the obvious way.  So if you know `n` and `p`, then

```
-- |Compute the inverse of a in the finite field K[x]/p with K=Z/nZ
inverse a (n, p) = let (s, t) = xgcd p a
                       r      = s * p + t * a
                    in if degree r > 0
                         then Nothing
                         else let Just r' = inverse' (project r) n
                               in Just $ r' * t
```

---

As an aside, if I were doing this, I would probably build on the definition of the `Integral` class in Haskell, and define a new class

```
class Integral a => FiniteField a where
    degree  :: a -> Integer
    xgcd    :: a -> a -> (a, a)
    inverse :: a -> a
```

which would have some simple instances (prime fields, which can be represented with a data type like)

```
data PrimeField = PF { size :: Integer, element :: Integer }
```

and more complicated instances for non-prime finite fields, whose elements are polynomials, probably represented with a `Map` -

```
data NonPrimeField = NPF {
    prime     :: Integer
  , maxDegree :: Integer
  , element   :: Map Integer Integer
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A more theoretical approach to augment Chris's awesome answer:

Given F = Z/(p), f and u in F[x], you can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find v and w in F[x] such that

```
uv + fw = gcd(u, f)
```

Now, if `f` is irreducible and `u` is not divisible by `f` their greatest common divisor `r = gcd(u,f)` is a unit. That is, `vu + wf = r`, with r in `F\{0}`. From this equation you get the congruence:

```
uv = r (mod f)       <=>        uvr⁻¹ = 1 (mod f)
```

where r<sup>-1</sup> is the multiplicative inverse of r in F.

Therefore the multiplicative inverse of the congruence class of `u` is `vr⁻¹` in F[x]/(f).

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is correct. Even if the inputs `u` and `f` are coprime, the extended Euclidean algorithm is only guaranteed to generate `v`, `w` such that `vu+wf=r` where `r` is a polynomial of degree `0` -- not necessarily the multiplicative unit. You must multiply `v` by `1/r` (considered as an element of `F`) in order to get the multiplicative inverse of `u`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: You are right Chris: GCD is unique up to multiplication by a unit, so `gcd(u,f)` can be any element in `F\{0}`. This has to be taken to account.